# Bootstrap 5.3 custom menu not working (not opening menu)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5.3 and created my own menu like so:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="site-branding">
      <!-- My Logo -->
    </div>

    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation navbar">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    </nav>
    <!-- #site-navigation -->

  </div>
  <div class="new-menu collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">aaaa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">bbbb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">cccc</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">aaaa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">bbbb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">cccc</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">aaaa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">bbbb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">cccc</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">aaaa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">bbbb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">cccc</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- #masthead -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But when I click the button my menu does not appear. I was following the example here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/#external-content

Anyone know why its not working?

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? Did you include all the necessary BS files?

Comment: I get no errors, I did not include all BS files, I will look into that right meow

Comment: By BS do you mean JS? Because I have them

Comment: I mean all the required Bootstrap files, CSS and JS. I also tested your code on codeply and it works

Comment: Yes I do have them

Comment: OK, well I updated your question to include the needed BS files and it seems to also work fine here now